# Moving an Image from side to side using Parallax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parallax, react-spring

Currently I'm using [react-spring/parallax](https://react-spring.io/components/parallax) for the parallax effect of my webpage. Currently what I want to achieve is this, where initially the image is at the center at the screen but as you scroll down the image moves from the center to the left:

[image]

Currently this is my codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sunset-sye04?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<Parallax pages={5}>
        <ParallaxLayer offset={0} speed={0.5} style={{ ...alignCenter, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <p className={styles.scrollText}>Scroll down</p>
        </ParallaxLayer>

        <ParallaxLayer sticky={{ start: 1, end: 3 }} style={{ ...alignCenter, justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
          <div className={`${styles.card} ${styles.sticky}`}>
            <img
              style={{ objectFit: 'cover', width: '180px' }}
              src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
            />
          </div>
        </ParallaxLayer>

        <ParallaxLayer offset={1.5} speed={1.5} style={{ ...alignCenter, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <div className={`${styles.card} ${styles.parallax} ${styles.purple}`}>
            <p>Minimum Investment</p>
          </div>
        </ParallaxLayer>

        <ParallaxLayer offset={2.5} speed={1.5} style={{ ...alignCenter, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <div className={`${styles.card} ${styles.parallax} ${styles.blue}`}>
            <p>Neither am I</p>
          </div>
        </ParallaxLayer>
      </Parallax>
```

Comment: At the very least I have now learned that I don't qualify for a Vanatu passport.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk hahahaXD